# Can I load data from my Mac directly into Snowflake?

Tags: json, file-upload, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I load json data from my Mac directly into Snowflake?

Or is there a way in the Snowflake Console (either classic or new) to load json data directly into a database I have created, in order to conduct further analysis?

Comment: Yes.  You can load data directly to Snowflake using the GUI or by using another connector (such as python, JDBC, ODBC, etc.) as well as SnowSQL.  Check the documentation as there are a lot of examples that will you show you.

Comment: Loading from UI: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-web-ui.html